# Display featured image on month view under an event title with event calendar plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i'm using "the event calendar" plugin on wordpress (with PRO version). And i'm trying to display the featured image of an event under the title.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlSzF.png

But i can't find the right php file to edit. I've tried to edit the "single-event.php" file in event-calendar/src/views/month/single-event.php" with the line

`<?php echo tribe_event_featured_image( $event_id, 'full', true ); ?>`

but nothing happened...
And the documentation doesn't help me as well.
If someone knows how or which file to edit, this will help me

Comment: You might want to ask on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where people know about this sort of thing.  And, you're using the paid, PRO, version of the plugin. Ask the plugin developer: support usually comes with paid plugins.

Comment: oh thanks for the advise ! i'll check that 